# Generic class and non static method

Tags: java, generics, instance, type-parameter

We have following code:

```
class MyClass<T>{
    public void method(){
        List<T>= new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

Does the following reason is correct? We are trying to instanciate `ArrayList<T>`, where `T` is type parameter, from a non static method. `method` needs in a specific instance of `MyClass<T>`. For instanciate `MyClass<T>` compiler must know type `T` explicitly. As i understood, compiler mark type parametr `T` in a non static context as known and hence we can instanciate `ArrayList<T>`.

But if we write the following code:

```
class MyClass<T>{
    public void method(){
        List<T>= new ArrayList<T>();
        new T();// Compile Error
    }
}
```

We have a compile error. I know that we can apply abstract factory pattern or use reflection for that needs. But `new` operator requires a specific type. Type parametr `T` is specific i non static context. Where i've wrong reasoning?

Comment: How can you guarantee there's a parameterless constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As i understood, compiler mark type parametr T in a non static context as known and hence we can instanciate ArrayList.

No. Even in non-static context, compiler doesn't know what type `T` denotes. The reason why `new ArrayList<T>();` works is, compiler knows that `ArrayList<E>` has a 0-arg constructor. The type parameter `T` will just be replaced by actual type argument. And it can be any type. And since you can create an `ArrayList` of anytype, that is fine.

> But new operator requires a specific type. Type parametr T is specific i non static context. Where i've wrong reasoning?

In case of `new T();`, again since the compiler doesn't know what type `T` is, hence it doesn't know, whether there is any accessible 0-arg constructor of `T` or not. Consider a class as below:

```
class Test {
    private int value;
    public Test(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

And then you instantiate your generic class as:

```
MyClass<Test> obj = new MyClass<Test>();
```

Now, assume that compiler allows `new T();`, then for this instantiation, it is like doing - `new Test();`. But there is no 0-arg constructor in `Test`. So, how would you expect that code to behave at runtime? It would certainly throw exception. This is what compiler prevents, by showing a compiler error.

We can add more information to the type parameter `T` by specifying a bound - `T extends Number`. But that will only allow us to access methods of type parameter. Constructor is still not accessible.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for exhaustive answer! But i have two following questions: 1.Let we doesnt define a constructor explicitly. Does we have in this case an empty default 0-argument constructor? 2. When we call `new` operator compiler checked for existing construtor with given parametrs?

Comment: @St.Antario. 1. Yes the compiler adds a default 0-arg constructor in that case, but the point is not that. Compiler cannot know the type of `T` at compile time. So, it won't allow such usage. 2. Whenever you create an object of a class, compiler would search of appropriate constructor. If not found, it would show compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

How would the compiler know that class T(that doesn't exist at runtime) would have a constructor with no arguments? As there is no way to guarantee this, clearly it should not be allowed!